# Applying a KML Layer to a Google Maps API within an Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I'm in the dark here. I'm trying to apply a KML Layer to a Google Maps API within an Android App using Android studio, but it seems impossible. I have exported the KML from a custom map on Google My Maps and also tried a KMZ as well, but, when I put the file into the /res/raw and try to invoke it, nothing shows up.

I managed to get some headway by having white pin-drops only show on the Google Maps API within the Android app, but it doesn't display names when the user clicks on each pin. I need these pins to have colors and styles - that's why I'm choosing KML instead of JSON but I can't find a lot of info about this.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

just donwload the android-maps-utils and modify the kml example in it,

here the link https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils